# Notepad++ use regex to search strings longer than 30 characters and ignore periods if any

Tags: regex

I am an Oracle DBA and need help with searching using Notepad++. Here is the requirement. I have a huge DDL script generated through Erwin. I want to find out if any constraint name is longer than 30 characters. The problem is that sometimes Erwin appends schema name and table name to the constraint name. I have to ignore these when searching for constraint names longer than 30 characters.

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE ABC_REPORTING.T_ABCDE_INSPTN_INVESN_SUM_HIST
                ADD CONSTRAINT PK_T_ABCDE_INSPTN_INVSN_SUM_HIST 
                PRIMARY KEY (COL_INSPTN, COL_SEQ_HIST);
```

I have to search all strings where constraint name `PK_T_ABCDE_INSPTN_INVSN_SUM_HIST` is longer than 30 characters.

If the constraint is named as `ABC.DEF.PK_T_ABCDE_INSPTN_INVSN_SUM_HIST`, then I have to ignore `ABC.DEF`.

If the constraint name is `ABC.PK_T_ABCDE_INSPTN_INVSN_SUM_HIST`, then I have to ignore `ABC`..

The constraint name always comes after `ADD CONSTRAINT` so this is the only name I have to check.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you need is:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT \s*(.+\.)*([^\.\s]{30,})
```

Between '' is the part of regex to be explained:

'`ADD CONSTRAINT`' Find the exact word.

'`\s*`'            Followed of a blank, that can appear zero or more times.

'`(.+\.)*`'        Followed of any character with a dot in the end, that group can appear zero or many times. This is for ignore ABC. and ABC.DEF ABC.BCE.XXX and on and on.

'`([^\.\s]{30,})`' And finally any character different to dot or blank, 30 or more times.

[Notepad regex reference](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want

```
([A-Z_](?!\.)){30,}
```

It won't match the `.` although if you have a really long schema or table name (that is, either is 30+ characters) those will match too, minus their last character.

What this regex does is look for "any character (A-Z capitalized or an underscore) that is not followed by a literal period" 30 or more times.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\w` (word char, which includes the underscore) to match your name:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT.*\w{31,}$
```

will find all the hits you seek. I added the `$` in case you have schema names longer than 30 chars.